# What's wrong with my Vue "wheel.vue" component? When it renders to html, It appears empty?

Tags: vue.js, components

I'm expecting a wheel like the one found here  (http://bl.ocks.org/jrue/a2aaf36b3c096925ccbf) , but the contents of the component seem empty.

I googled, and found several similar questions about components not rendering, but none seemed to address my issue.

I'm trying to create a wheel component (using Vue 2.6).

I know how to create a basic vue component and know how to import that component into the App.vue, so I don't understand why my code is not working.

The first pic below shows when the vue app runs, the  tag is there, but where's the Wheel?
The second pic below shows the Elements with id="chart" and id="question", but they seem to be empty.

Below is code for my Wheel.vue and App.vue.

[image]

[image]

```
//Wheel.vue
<template>
    <div class="wheelclass">
        <div id="chart">seeme</div>
        <div id="question"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
export default {
    name: "wheel",
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    created() {
        let myscript = document.createElement("script");
        myscript.setAttribute("src", "https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js");
        document.head.appendChild(myscript);
    },
};

//begin code for wheel
var padding = { top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 0, left: 0 },
    w = 500 - padding.left - padding.right,
    h = 500 - padding.top - padding.bottom,
    r = Math.min(w, h) / 2,
    rotation = 0,
    oldrotation = 0,
    picked = 100000,
    oldpick = [],
    color = d3.scale.category20(); //category20c()
//randomNumbers = getRandomNumbers();

 var data = [
                    {"label":"Question 1",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for specifying the area between the content and its border?"}, // padding
                    {"label":"Question 2",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the font?"}, //font-family
                    {"label":"Question 3",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the color of text?"}, //color
                    {"label":"Question 4",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the boldness of text?"}, //font-weight
                    {"label":"Question 5",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the size of text?"}, //font-size
                    {"label":"Question 6",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the background color of a box?"}, //background-color
                    {"label":"Question 7",  "value":1,  "question":"Which word is used for specifying an HTML tag that is inside another tag?"}, //nesting
                    {"label":"Question 8",  "value":1,  "question":"Which side of the box is the third number in: margin:1px 1px 1px 1px; ?"}, //bottom
                    {"label":"Question 9",  "value":1,  "question":"What are the fonts that don't have serifs at the ends of letters called?"}, //sans-serif
                    {"label":"Question 10", "value":1, "question":"With CSS selectors, what character prefix should one use to specify a class?"}, //period
                    {"label":"Question 11", "value":1, "question":"With CSS selectors, what character prefix should one use to specify an ID?"}, //pound sign
                    {"label":"Question 12", "value":1, "question":"In an HTML document, which tag holds all of the content people see?"}, //<body>
                    {"label":"Question 13", "value":1, "question":"In an HTML document, which tag indicates an unordered list?"}, //<ul>
                    {"label":"Question 14", "value":1, "question":"In an HTML document, which tag indicates the most important heading of your document?"}, //<h1>
                    {"label":"Question 15", "value":1, "question":"What CSS property is used for specifying the area outside a box?"}, //margin
                    {"label":"Question 16", "value":1, "question":"What type of bracket is used for HTML tags?"}, //< >
                    {"label":"Question 17", "value":1, "question":"What type of bracket is used for CSS rules?"}, // { }
                    {"label":"Question 18", "value":1, "question":"Which HTML tag is used for specifying a paragraph?"}, //<p>
                    {"label":"Question 19", "value":1, "question":"What should always be the very first line of code in your HTML?"}, //<!DOCTYPE html>
                    {"label":"Question 20", "value":1, "question":"What HTML tag holds all of the metadata tags for your page?"}, //<head>
                    {"label":"Question 21", "value":1, "question":"In CSS, what character separates a property from a value?"}, // colon
                    {"label":"Question 22", "value":1, "question":"What HTML tag holds all of your CSS code?"}, // <style>
                    {"label":"Question 23", "value":1, "question":"What file extension should you use for your web pages?"}, // .html
                    {"label":"Question 24", "value":1, "question":"Which coding language is used for marking up content and structure on a web page?"}, // HTML
                    {"label":"Question 25", "value":1, "question":"Which coding language is used for specifying the design of a web page?"}, // CSS
                    {"label":"Question 26", "value":1, "question":"Which coding language is used for adding functionality to a web page?"}, // JavaScript
                    {"label":"Question 27", "value":1, "question":"What CSS property is used for making the edges of a box visible?"}, // border
                    {"label":"Question 28", "value":1, "question":"What character symbol is used at the end of each CSS statement?"},//semi-colon
                    {"label":"Question 29", "value":1, "question":"By default, how wide is a <div> box?"}, //100%
                    {"label":"Question 30", "value":1, "question":"What character symbol do I use to specify multiple CSS selectors in one code block?"} //comma
        ];

var svg = d3
    .select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .data([data1])
    .attr("width", w + padding.left + padding.right)
    .attr("height", h + padding.top + padding.bottom);

var container = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "chartholder")
    .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" +
            (w / 2 + padding.left) +
            "," +
            (h / 2 + padding.top) +
            ")"
    );

var vis = container.append("g");

var pie = d3.layout
    .pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function (d) {
        return 1;
    });

// declare an arc generator function
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

// select paths, use arc generator to draw
var arcs = vis
    .selectAll("g.slice")
    .data(pie)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "slice");

arcs.append("path")
    .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return color(i);
    })
    .attr("d", function (d) {
        return arc(d);
    });

// add the text
arcs.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        d.innerRadius = 0;
        d.outerRadius = r;
        d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2;
        return (
            "rotate(" +
            ((d.angle * 180) / Math.PI - 90) +
            ")translate(" +
            (d.outerRadius - 10) +
            ")"
        );
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function (d, i) {
        return data1[i].label;
    });

container.on("click", spin);

function spin(d) {
    container.on("click", null);

    //all slices have been seen, all done
    console.log("OldPick: " + oldpick.length, "Data length: " + data1.length);
    if (oldpick.length == data1.length) {
        console.log("done");
        container.on("click", null);
        return;
    }

    var ps = 360 / data1.length,
        pieslice = Math.round(1440 / data1.length),
        rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1440 + 360);

    rotation = Math.round(rng / ps) * ps;

    picked = Math.round(data1.length - (rotation % 360) / ps);
    picked = picked >= data1.length ? picked % data1.length : picked;

    if (oldpick.indexOf(picked) !== -1) {
        d3.select(this).call(spin);
        return;
    } else {
        oldpick.push(picked);
    }

    rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps / 2);

    vis.transition()
        .duration(3000)
        .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
        .each("end", function () {
            //mark question as seen
            d3.select(".slice:nth-child(" + (picked + 1) + ") path").attr(
                "fill",
                "#111"
            );

            //populate question
            d3.select("#question h1").text(data1[picked].question);

            oldrotation = rotation;

            container.on("click", spin);
        });
}

//make arrow
svg.append("g")
    .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" +
            (w + padding.left + padding.right) +
            "," +
            (h / 2 + padding.top) +
            ")"
    )
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M-" + r * 0.15 + ",0L0," + r * 0.05 + "L0,-" + r * 0.05 + "Z")
    .style({ fill: "black" });

//draw spin circle
container
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("r", 60)
    .style({ fill: "white", cursor: "pointer" });

//spin text
container
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 15)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("SPIN")
    .style({ "font-weight": "bold", "font-size": "30px" });

function rotTween(to) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(oldrotation % 360, rotation);
    return function (t) {
        return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
    };
}

function getRandomNumbers() {
    var array = new Uint16Array(1000);
    var scale = d3.scale.linear().range([360, 1440]).domain([0, 100000]);

    if (
        window.hasOwnProperty("crypto") &&
        typeof window.crypto.getRandomValues === "function"
    ) {
        window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
        console.log("works");
    } else {
        //no support for crypto, get crappy random numbers
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) + 1;
        }
    }

    return array;
}
//end code for wheel
</script>

<style type="text/css" scoped>
text {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
#chart {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#question {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 0;
    left: 520px;
}
#question h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
</style>
```

```
//App.vue

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
    <Wheel></Wheel>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import Wheel from './components/Wheel.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    Wheel
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Did you notice your code for wheel is out of export statement? how you want to render something when you didn't call them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said @Mohsen in his/her comment, your logic code is outside of the export statement.
To be precise, it should be in a mounted hook so that your are sure that the HTML is ready.

Also you should wait for d3 to be ready so your code should turn to something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
export default {
    name: "wheel",
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    mounted() { // changed to mounted because we need the HTML to be ready
        let myscript = document.createElement("script");
        myscript.setAttribute("src", "https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js");
        document.head.appendChild(myscript);

        // wait for library to be loaed before executing your code
        // don't worry it will keep instance's context
        // Vue automatically bind all methods to the instance
        myscript.onload = this.startWheelCode;
    },
    methods: {
      startWheelCode() { /* your wheel code here */ }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @darkylmnx. Although my solution fixed it, your answer seems more complete.  I edited my fix to be more like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @Mohsen.  The following fixed it.  I put all the wheel code into a method called createWheel() inside the default export, then called createWheel() from the "created" lifecycle hook.